# Validate if one field is present and valid

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, constraints

I just wanted to know how custom validation or any other solution would be implemented on a POJO. **My POJO has been used in many ways where i do not  need any kind of validation such as @NotBlank etc. However there is a scenario if i want to update at least one field inside it. Then validate it.** 
My POJO is provided in the request body and i want to validate if one of the field is provided then accept the request else don't. So far i have implemented it in a hard coded way. But i would like something which spring boot provides.

My pojo is below

```
public class Person {

    private String name;
    private String age;
    private String email;
    //etc .etc. getters and setters
}
```

Now if i want to update a person i want to validate if **a single field is provided in the Request Body then accept the payload** else throw constraint violation.

So far i have done it hard coded ie

```
private boolean isInValid(Person per) {
        if (per == null) {
            return true;
        }

        int changes = 0;
        changes = changes + (StringUtils.isBlank(per.getName()) ? 0 : 1);
        changes = changes + (StringUtils.isBlank(per.getEmail()) ? 0 : 1);
//etc etc...
        return changes == 0;
    }
```

I would like something that spring boot provides.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is not enough standard Hibernate Validator checks, you can [implement your own validators](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-mvc-custom-validator) using your custom logic